# How can I resolve the error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading'?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dispatcher, visual-studio-addins

I am writing an Add-in for Visual Studio 2017. I use the following:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(()=>
{
// ...
});
```

But I keep getting the compiler warning: `VSTHRD001 Avoid legacy thread switching methods` and since I can be a bit obsessive, I researched [the warning](https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-threading/blob/master/doc/analyzers/VSTHRD001.md), and applied the "fix":

```
ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory.Run(()=>
{
  // ...
});
```

Since applying the fix, the method won't even run, upon further investigation, it's throwing the error: `'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading, Version=15.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'`

I'm using the nuget package `<package id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading" version="15.7.18" targetFramework="net461" />` and I have the binding redirects from installing the package in my app.config: `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-15.7.0.0" newVersion="15.7.0.0" />`

I've downgraded the package and even tried changing the redirect version but to no avail. For the only other similar related issue, Microsoft insists [it's not a bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/187058/tfs-20173-mtm-controler-missing-dll-referance.html).

I'm using Visual studio 15.7.3 and that dll in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies is version 15.6.27-beta+gca...

Any ideas? Yes `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke` works perfect.

Comment: Does `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-15.7.0.0" newVersion="15.7.0.0" />` include version 15.7.18 in the sense that 0 is a catch-all (I don't think this is the case)? Have you tried changing `newVersion` to `15.7.18` or `15.7.18.0`

Comment: @MarkusDeibel It didn't work because the problem is related to the version that Visual studio ships.

Comment: What worked was downgrading `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading` to 15.6.44, with binding redirect is `oldVersion="0.0.0.0-15.6.0.0" newVersion="15.6.0.0"`. Now I have **2** new IDE1002 warnings because of the Analyzer assemblies! How ironic.

Comment: For other's reference downgrading to 15.6.44 from 15.8.145 worked for me too

Comment: The commit [here](https://github.com/madskristensen/AutoLoadPackageManager/commit/cd56c81c982fba066144af3463f57369ae9b6dbd) from Mads implements the downgrade too.

Comment: I had this after installing AWS toolkit. What worked for me was to install the latest updates for Visual Studio.